# Does there exist a maximal subset of arithmetic progressions of length $k,$ such that any additional numbers will result in an A.P. of length $k+2?$

Tags: number-theory, arithmetic-progressions, ramsey-theory, arithmetic-combinatorics

Fix $k\in\mathbb{N}.$ Definition: A set $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ (with $\vert A \vert = \infty$) is *maximal of length $k$* if it contains at least one arithmetic progression of length $k,$ and, if $x\not\in A,$ then $A\cup\{x\}$ will contain an arithmetic progression of length $>k;$ equivalently, $A$ will no longer only contain A.P.'s of length $\leq k.$

An example of a Set $A$ which is maximal of length $2$ is the following "Greedy (algorithm)" [Salem-Spencer set:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salem%E2%80%93Spencer_set) $\quad$ [A003278](https://oeis.org/A003278) .

My question is this:

> Does there exist $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ that is maximal of length $k,$
> such that if $x\not\in A,$ then
> $A\cup\{x\}$ will contain an arithmetic
> progression of length $\geq k+2 ?$
>
> [This would mean that there is no $x\in A$ which (only) brings the length of the greatest A.P. of $A$ up to $k+1.$]

I'm guessing that a general example can be constructed, but I can't quite think how to do so.

Comment: The title is a bit confusing. For example, it should say $k+1$ instead of $k+2$, shouldn't it?

Comment: @Nulhomologous No, I'm not sure what you mean. If we replaced $k+2$ with $k+1$ in the title the question would be trivial, because if we append any additional numbers to a *maximal set (of length $k$)*, $A$, then this will create an A.P. of length $k+1,$ by the very definition of *maximal set (of length $k$)* as I defined in the question.

Comment: The definition of *maximal set of length $k$* is the *entire first paragraph* of the question. Definition: A set $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ (with $\vert A \vert = \infty$) is *maximal of length $k$* if it contains at least one arithmetic progression of length $k,$ and, if $x\not\in A,$ then $A\cup\{x\}$ will contain an arithmetic progression of length $>k;$ equivalently, $A$ will no longer only contain A.P.'s of length $\leq k.$

Comment: I suspect (but no proof) that if we work in base $k$, and let $A$ be the set of all the elements that has an even number of 0's (ignore leading 0's), then that works. In fact, the addition of any other element might result in an AP of length around $2k-3$.